# Docker Registry Pull error

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I have a docker registry that is currently up and running. I have two different VMs that host docker. One I created myself and manually installed docker. The other was made by BOSH. Now both VMs are able to push images up to my private registry at `<IP>:<PORT>`. The manually created VM is able to pull whatever images exist in the registry. In comparison the BOSH VM is only able to pull the images that it pushed up.

When pulling an image it pushed we get output like so

```
<IP>:<PORT>/test/scratch:1: The image you are pulling has been verified. Important: image verification is a tech preview feature and should not be relied on to provide security.
```

However when pulling any other image (that I know exists and can be pulled) I get output as follows:

```
docker pull <IP>:<PORT>/<IMAGE_PREFIX>/centos:6
6: Pulling from <IP>:<PORT>/<IMAGE_PREFIX>/centos
f1b10cd84249: Pulling fs layer
b9aeeaeb5e17: Pulling fs layer
f577f0104d9f: Pulling fs layer
25026cb4e110: Pulling fs layer
7935ccc5687c: Pulling fs layer
b65d7f315ddb: Pulling fs layer
0995c5f045e3: Pulling fs layer
8383060ffe2b: Pulling fs layer
4e532e3dd806: Pulling fs layer
13012e69774f: Pulling fs layer
c0720f93f003: Pulling fs layer
1af9b43df076: Pulling fs layer
961ad276c59a: Download complete
Pulling repository <IP>:<PORT>/<IMAGE_PREFIX>/centos
FATA[0000] Error: image <IMAGE_PREFIX>/centos:6 not found
```

It doesn't make sense that the BOSH VM "can't find" the image because it clearly sees the layers that are used to create the image I want. But I have no idea if this is some strange verification error or not.

The output from `ps -ef | grep docker` in the BOSH VM shows:

```
docker --daemon --api-enable-cors=false --debug=false --group vcap --graph 
/var/vcap/store/docker/docker --host unix:///var/run/docker.sock 
--insecure-registry <IP>:<PORT> --bip 192.168.227.1/24 --icc=true --ip-forward=true 
--iptables=true --iptables=true --pidfile /var/vcap/sys/run/docker/docker.pid 
--selinux-enabled=false --host tcp://127.0.0.1:4243
```

The output for my manually created VM shows:

```
/usr/bin/docker -d --bip 192.168.227.1/24 --insecure-registry <IP>:<PORT>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my error. The registry contained images built using docker 1.7.0, however my BOSH VM has docker 1.5.0 installed. Therefore the BOSH VM didn't recognize the image format (I believe) that the registry contained and hence reported a not found error for the image I desired. Upgrading the docker binary and spec file, and then redeploying the new release fixed the error.